# How to fix this ABB MS325 circuit breaker?

Tags: switches, circuit-breaker

I have couple broken training bench circuit breakers.
The broken part is the manual switch.

[image: broken switch]

I uninstalled one and tried to open it. I was able to open the back side which contains metal connectors and springs.

---

Update1:

Hi, I tried to pull the livers from the two sides but it's rock solid.

Here's a photo of the 2 notches for the knob, but also aligning the knob with the notches didn't help to remove the knob. I might break it eventually but I would like to try possible solutions.

[image: knob notches]

Here're the sides livers:

[image: left side]

This is the back:

[image: the back]

First back disassemble:

[image]

Taking out the parts to check if there are screws for the front side:

[image: internal parts]

So the back only opens to the metal parts. I can't get to the knob !

---

Update2:

I removed the knob, the spring might be broken. But I can't open the spring area:

[image: aligned notches]

I was able to removed the knob. But I can't get into the spring area.

[image: knob is removed]

---

Update3:

I opened the front cover, now it's about finding the broken part.

But I think I have to open a working one to know where is the issue.

[image: open front cover]

Comment: IS it the plastic that stripped? Can it be pulled off and fixed with Polyurethane 3 day cure? Or 2 part cryanoacrylate

Comment: Request an RMA 100000 cycle rating is false with normal use, I assume. Defective workmanship.

Comment: The problem is that I want to disassemble the circuit breaker to reach the manual switch but I can't. I'm afraid that I have to break it anyway since it going to be thrown out. The department is willing to purchase couple one but they are a bit expensive.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 It is obvious that it is a misuse case, because it didn't broke from its own, someone broke the on/off switch.

Comment: Sometimes normal operating  torque exceeds  small shaft retention in plastic. Then it's a design flaw. It's just a 4A 3ph switch at high voltage

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 What do you mean by "normal operating torque" ? Do you mean students physical force to enable/disable the manual switch or the load connected to training bench ?

Comment: It should be a spring loaded switch like a circuit breaker except rotary so you shouldn't have to jam it to the end you just have to flip it till it toggles, I assume. The end stops should be rugged

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Anyway, since it's going to be thrown away, I would like to break it and check what is inside. And maybe upload a photo to this post.

Comment: Is knob removable?, Are my assumptions on string force end-stop accurate.

Comment: Yes, that's an important question. I tried to remove the knob with a screw driver, there are also two notches under the knob and seem with be aligned to allow the knob to be removed. I tried to align the knob and take the knob out but I couldn't and almost break it.

I don't know about the spring connected with the knob because I couldn't open that area. But let me check it tomorrow and post the updates.

Comment: There may be some kind of retainer be picked like a lock to pull off with 2 levers for even forces

Comment: I updated the post, but with no benefit. Still can't get to the knob :)

Comment: I just noticed a hole in the knob. That's where it is fastened.  Look down the hole for a screw head.

Comment: This question will likely be better off at https://diy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Lundin Hi, is there a way to move the whole post to the other forum ? I'm thinking it's not possible because I haven't noticed that in Stack forums. But anyway I hope this post would remain as a reference after I solve the fix problem and maybe post it in diy later.

Answer (score 3):

There most likely is no parts inside that are meant to be serviced by users.

For safety reasons, buy a new one.

Comment: I thought so. There are no screws for the front side. There are 4 screws at the back, which opens to springs and metal contacts.